# Injecting a dependency before startup

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.1, .net-core-3.1

I have a type that I want to use in Startup of my .net core 3.1 app.

Here is the class I want to inject:

```
public class DbConnectionStringManager
{
    public readonly string ConnectionStringForDefault;

    public readonly string ConnectionStringForLogDb;

    public DbConnectionStringManager(ConnectionStringProviderFactory factory)
    {
        var defaultConnectionStringProvider = factory.Create(ConnectionString.Default);
        var logDbConnectionStringProvider = factory.Create(ConnectionString.LogDb);

        ConnectionStringForDefault = defaultConnectionStringProvider.GetConnectionString();
        ConnectionStringForLogDb = logDbConnectionStringProvider.GetConnectionString();
    }
}
```

Another class I need to use

```
public class ConnectionStringProviderFactory
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    protected readonly AwsSecretProvider _awsSecretProvider;

    public ConnectionStringProviderFactory(IConfiguration configuration, AwsSecretProvider awsSecretProvider)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
        _awsSecretProvider = awsSecretProvider;
    }

    public AbsConnectionStringProvider Create(ConnectionString connectionString)
        => connectionString switch
        {
            ConnectionString.Default => new DefaultConnectionStringProvider(_configuration, _awsSecretProvider),
            ConnectionString.LogDb => new LogDbConnectionStringProvider(_configuration, _awsSecretProvider),
            _ => throw new InvalidOperationException($"No ConnectionStringProvider created for requested source : {connectionString}"),
        };

    public enum ConnectionString
    {
        Default,
        LogDb
    }
}
```

And lastly

```
public class AwsSecretProvider
{
    private GetSecretValueResponse _response = null;

    public DatabaseSecret GetSecret(string secretName)
    {
        //Some code
    }
}
```

I tried this at my Program.cs for injecting dependencies before startup

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder
                    .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, config) => { config.ClearProviders(); })
                    .UseKestrel(options =>
                        {
                            options.AllowSynchronousIO = true;
                            options.Limits.MinRequestBodyDataRate = null;
                        })
                    .UseIISIntegration()
                     .ConfigureServices(serviceCollection =>
                     {
                         serviceCollection.AddSingleton<AwsSecretProvider>();
                         serviceCollection.AddSingleton<ConnectionStringProviderFactory>();
                         serviceCollection.AddSingleton<DbConnectionStringManager>();
                     })
                    .UseIIS()
                    .UseStartup<Startup>();
            }));

}
```

When I run the app, I get the following error

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Unable to resolve service for type
> 'Hesapkurdu.Services.Encryption.Database.DbConnectionStringManager'
> while attempting to activate 'Hesapkurdu.WebApi.Startup'.'

Comment: I am using AWS Secrets Manager (a kind of vault) for storing db credentials @Fildor

Comment: Use method injection. You can resolve `DbConnectionStringManager` on `Configure` method of `Startup` class.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the fact that it happens when trying to activate `Startup`, it looks like you are trying to inject `DbConnectionStringManager` directly into `Startup` constructor.

That wont work.

> Only the following services can be injected into the `Startup`
> constructor when using the Generic Host (`IHostBuilder`):
>
> - IWebHostEnvironment
> - IHostEnvironment
> - IConfiguration
>
> Any service
> registered with the DI container can be injected into the
> `Startup.Configure` method:

For example

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, DbConnectionStringManager connections) {
    //...
}
```

Reference [Dependency injection in ASP.NET Core - Services injected into Startup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0#services-injected-into-startup)